# Android Studio Edit Text prints wrong input in the Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext

When I provide input to the Edit Text from my Laptop Keyboard, it prints (takes wrong input) jargon.
For example typing "London" from my Keyboard prints "øóñðóñ". The number "12345" print as "²²¤€"

I have tried changing the Edit Text multiple times but no use. The input from the emulator keyboard prints just fine. There was no error like this a few hours ago.

The code for Edit Text xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/cityText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

Comment: Did you change the locale from the settings of the emulator?

Comment: I do not remember messing with any emulator settings

Comment: Solved it. Some combination of Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Left Arrow Key works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Some combination of Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Left Arrow Key works!